# Copying one vector into another starting at some position

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Say I have two vectors

```
auto a = std::vector<int>{10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
auto b = std::vector<int>{21, 22, 23};
```

and I want to copy the entire content of `b` into `a` starting at some position (let's say `4`), possibly overriding elements and resizing the vector, so that the resulting vector `a` looks like

```
[10, 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23]
```

Is there some function in the STL (maybe in `<algorithm>` or `) that does exactly that?

Comment: What would be the result if `b` was just `[21]`? `[10, 11, 12, 13, 21, 15]` or `[10, 11, 12, 13, 21]`?

Comment: I would then need to be `[10, 11, 12, 13, 21, 15]`. Basically, I want to write a file-like interface to a `std::vector` where the starting position can be set via a `seek()` function and the above copying is used in the `write()` function.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of C++20 [`<ranges>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges)

```
auto a = std::vector{10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
auto b = std::vector{21, 22, 23};

auto pos = 4;
auto c = a | std::views::drop(pos);
auto sz = c.size();
std::ranges::copy(b | std::views::take(sz), c.begin());
std::ranges::copy(b | std::views::drop(sz), std::back_inserter(a));
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WWq1cr6jr)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
    auto a = std::vector<int>{ 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
    auto b = std::vector<int>{ 21, 22, 23 };

    int from = 4; //from which index

    a.insert(a.begin() + from, b.begin(), b.end());
    a.resize(from + b.size());

    for (auto i : a) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
```

Comment: Note that OP does not want to resize if `from + b.size() < a.size()`. Your solution loses values in that case.

Comment: Morever, insertions will shift the data, not overwrite them, which does not fit OP's specifications.

Answer (score 0):

There's no ready-made algorithm to do it. You can implement it yourself like this:

```cpp
auto a = std::vector<int>{10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
auto b = std::vector<int>{21, 22, 23};

std::size_t insertionPoint = 4;
std::size_t elemCount = std::max(insertionPoint + b.size(), a.size());
a.resize(elemCount);
std::copy(std::cbegin(b), std::cend(b), std::begin(a) + insertionPoint);
```

**Note:**

- This requires the value type of `std::vector` (i.e., in this case, `int`) to be default constructible.
- If `insertionPoint` is greater than `a.size()` you'll get default constructed elements between the last element of `a` (before the insertion) and the first inserted element from `b`.